# Activity objects still alive after pressing the Back Button

Tags: performance

everyone!

I am new to programming, but very interested in Android app development, and have read many books, articles, and tutorials, and have watched many videos on the topic.

I have been trying to create a personal app that displays artworks drawn on the Android canvas, and it is working, but the problem is that it consumes too much memory. I have recently integrated code to take a heap dump at 3 different points in the normal use of the app, and found that 2 copies of the gallery Activity sometimes exist at the same time.

However, the problem seems really complicated...

The app has 3 Activities:

Activity A ~ shows two buttons. Clicking the first button will start Activity B.

Activity B ~ shows a list of 60 items, each of which has a unique data set. Clicking any item on the list will put the item's data set as intent extras, and then start Activity C.

Activity C ~ initially shows the first digital art. Swiping will show the succeeding digital arts.

The entire app is always in portrait mode ~ the Manifest includes

android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Each of the activities uses static inner classes to define threads, and uses recycle() on bitmaps in the onDestroy method. The onDestroy method also nulls out variables.

Drawing on the Android Canvas always happens in a background thread.

None of the activities uses static variables to reference views or other objects.

Activity C does not use any onClickListener; it uses onTouchEvent instead.

The following is the test that I use in generating heap dumps.

1. Launch the app. Activity A starts.
2. Click on button B. Activity B starts.
3. Inside Activity B, I click on the first item. Activity C starts.
4. Inside Activity C, I swipe to see all ten digital arts. Then, I tap on the Android Back Button. This destroys Activity C, and restarts Activity B.
5. I repeat Steps 4 and 5, going from the second item on Activity B's list to the ninth item. Each of these items puts unique intent extras before starting Activity C.
6. For the tenth item, I repeat Step 4, while code inside Activity C tests for a particular intent extra. I swipe to see 6 more digital arts, and when the code tests True, it produces the first heap dump.
7. I click on the Android Back Button, destroying Activity C, and restarting Activity B.
8. Inside Activity B, I click on the Android Back Button, destroying Activity B, and restarting Activity A.
9. Code inside Activity A detects a restart, and produces the second heap dump.
10. I repeat Steps 2, 3, and 4.
11. I repeat Step 8.
12. Code inside Activity A detects a second restart, and produces the third heap dump.

On one test run, MAT reported that while I was inside Activity C, two Activity C objects were present. In the Leak  Suspects section, MAT displayed the following:

The thread java.lang.Thread @ 0x41e1c6c8 FinalizerWatchdogDaemon keeps local variables with total size 15,429,232 (32.64%) bytes.

The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.view.View[]" loaded by "".

Of course, this is rare.

On most tests, MAT reports only one Activity C object. HOWEVER, and this is the big problem, I think, when I am inside Activity C, and then press the back button to go back to Activity B, and then press the back button to go back to Activity A, the heap dump taken inside Activity A leads to the following MAT report:

Problem Suspect 1
10 instances of "android.widget.ImageView", loaded by "" occupy 15,367,680 (54.10%) bytes. 
Biggest instances:
1.  android.widget.ImageView @ 0x41eef9c0 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.

2. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x41ef3d28 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.
3. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x42118088 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.
4. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x4213fae0 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.
5. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x4382e838 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.
6. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x4382f6f8 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.
7. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x4382f920 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.
8. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x43834f70 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.
9. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x438442f8 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.
10. android.widget.ImageView @ 0x438852d0 - 1,536,768 (5.41%) bytes.

Problem Suspect 2
69 instances of "android.graphics.Bitmap", loaded by "" occupy 10,786,184 (37.97%) bytes. 
Biggest instances:
android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x41ed0b98 - 635,856 (2.24%) bytes.

Problem Suspect 1 are ImageViews from Activity C, but Activity C should already be destroyed. In the histogram section, MAT reports that one Activity C object is still present.

I am thinking that if I were really leaking memory (Activity C), then going A-B-C-B-C-B-C-B-C-...-B-C-B-A and checking out the bitmap galleries should produce many Activity C objects, maybe ten objects.

Problem Suspect 2 is the same issue. Most of the bitmaps in that problem suspect are from Activity B, which should already be destroyed. One Activity B object also appears in the histogram, when, in fact, the heap dump is taken inside Activity A (after pressing the back button inside Activity B).

Please help.

Notes:

1. I test on a real Android device running Jellybean (Android 4.2.2). The device screen resolution is width of 480 and height of 800. RAM is at 1GB, and I usually see 400MB free.
2. One issue that I have already resolved is a bitmap consuming 3456000 bytes. It turned out to be a PNG image set as a background for Activity A. However, it is still a puzzle ~ the PNG is 400×800. So, at ARGB_8888, shouldn't this PNG take only 480×800×4 = 1536000? 3456000 is actually 9 × (480×800).
3. The app works really fast, and does not report any ANR or Out Of Memory error. In addition, it is rare for the app to be janky. (When many other apps are open, and free RAM goes down to around 190MB, that is the situation when the UI seems laggy.)

I would appreciate any idea or insight or opinion. Thanks!